# Change tab of parent Window TabControl from child UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a parent window with a `TabControl` in it. Each tab contains a `UserControl` associated with it. In one of my `UserControl`, I have a button. When I click the button, I would like to change the selected tab of the `TabControl` that is in my parent window.

I'm using the MVVM pattern so if possible, I would like to do it in XAML with the Command property on my button.

For example:

```
<Button Content="Switch Tab" Command="{Binding SwitchTabCommand}" />
```

Thanks in advance my fellow programmers!

The parent window view model:

```
public class CoolViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
    public ITabViewModel SelectedTab { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public CoolViewModel()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>
        {
            new VeryNiceViewModel(),
            new VeryNiceViewModel()
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the code of a UserControl inside the tab:

```
public class VeryCoolViewModel : BaseViewModel, ITabViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public Test currentSelection { get; set; }
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    ICommand GoToOtherTab { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public GabaritSelecteurViewModel()
    {
        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>
        {
            new Test { Title = "Title #1" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #2" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #3" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #4" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #5" }
        };

        TabHeader = "Tests";

        GoToOtherTab = new RelayCommand(GoToTab, parameter => true);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void GoToTab(object parameter)
    {
        // I don't know how to tell to the
        // parent window to go to the other tab...
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And here's the XAML for the UserControl (that is inside the TabControl):

```
<Button Content="Go to the other tab" Command="{Binding GoToOtherTab}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something that is a bit "hacky" but is very simple. It would be less hacky if each of your UserControls wouldn't have had a ViewModel of it's own (not quite sure why that was needed.

Anyways, our goal is to get to `CoolViewModel`. How do we get there? `RelativeSource Binding`. In short, it enables you to bind in different scopes (other than your own `DataContext`, which is the UserControl in this example).

So, we know you have a `TabControl` which holds all of these UserControls and we know that this TabControl's `DataContext` is the `CoolViewModel`.

1. Put the `Command` in `CoolViewModel` like this:

   `public ICommand SwitchTabCommand {get;set;}`
2. Bind to it from withing the UserControl:

   `<Button Content="Go to the other tab" Command= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.SwitchTabCommand}" />`

So essentially you are looking for the nearest Ancestor `TabControl`, looking through it's `DataContext` for the Command `SwitchTabCommand`

Comment: If someone could  explain to me how to create code blocks that are nicely formatted, that would be great.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! The XAML Designer was complaining with `Path=DataContext.SwitchToCommand` so I had to change it to: `Path=DataContext.(viewModels:CoolViewModel.SwitchToCommand) because otherwise it was telling me this: _Cannot resolve property 'SwitchToCommand' in data context of type object_.

Comment: Yeah I did that in my answer...but it doesn't color the xaml and c#

Comment: Weird...was it a runtime issue or compilation issue only?

Comment: It was before compilation and runtime. It was underlined blue in the XAML code.

Comment: That might resolve itself when you run the code. You should try it just for the sport

Comment: Yeah it works even though it's underlined... I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add into VeryCoolViewModel(your UserControl VM) event:

```
public class VeryCoolViewModel : BaseViewModel, ITabViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public Test currentSelection { get; set; }
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }

    public delegate void ChangeSelectedTab(string tabName)
    public event ChangeSelectedTab OnChangeSelectedTab
    #endregion

    #region Commands

    ICommand GoToOtherTab { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public GabaritSelecteurViewModel()
    {
        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>
        {
            new Test { Title = "Title #1" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #2" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #3" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #4" },
            new Test { Title = "Title #5" }
        };

        TabHeader = "Tests";

        GoToOtherTab = new RelayCommand(GoToTab, parameter => true);
    }

    private void GoToTab(object parameter)
    {
            OnChangeSelectedTab?.Invoke((string)parameter);
    }
}
```

and into parent window VM in constuctor:

```
public CoolViewModel()
{
    Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>
    {
         new VeryNiceViewModel(),
         new VeryNiceViewModel()
    };
    Tabs.ForEach(x =>{
        x.OnChangeSelectedTab += x_OnChangeSelectedTab
    });

}

private void x_OnChangeSelectedTab(string tabName)
{
     // select from List of tabItems tabItem with name == tabName and then set propetry in this tabItem to true.
     SomePropertyInParentViewModel = true;
}
```

And in View:

```
<TabItem x:Name="TabWhatYouNeed" IsSelected="{Binding SomePropertyInParentViewModel}">
```